# Queue communication from serial thread to Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, pyserial

I am doing simple gui for continuous reading data stream from serial COM port and display the results. I could not get up and running queue to push the data from reading thread to main (GUI) part. I think I am missing some part but cannot figure out what.

I can easily start thread and read data(printing them after) from COM port but it seems nothing is going to queue becase when I am printing output in GUI part is empty. Beside that reading and main thread is running ok.
Do you have an idea how to check if is something in the queue?

Here is part of the code if you could check it.
And also sorry for messed up indention :-P
Thank you

```
class MyGUI(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.queueData = Queue.Queue() # create queue
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        """Create the GUI"""
        self.grid()

        ...gui code here...

    def processQueueData(self):
        try:
            rawData = self.queueData.get()
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            print 'GUI:'+ rawData
            #show result of the task
        finally:
            self.queueDataID = self.after(50, self.processQueueData)
```

And reading thread is here:

```
class MyProcess(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent, queueData): #def __init__(self, startValue)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop = False
        self.parent = parent
        self.queueData = queueData
        try:
            port = app.boxPort.get()
            self.ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=19200, timeout=0, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
        except serial.SerialException:
            print ('Cannot open port')
            self.stop()
        else:
            app.labelConStatus.set(u'Connected to ' + port)

    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True
        try:
            self.ser.close()
        except serial.SerialException:
            print ('Cannot close port')
        else:
            app.labelConStatus.set(u'Disconnected')

    def run (self):
        while self._stop  == False:
            data = self.ser.read(1)
            n = self.ser.inWaiting()
            if n:
                data = data + self.ser.read(n)
            self.queueData.put(data)
        #   print 'PORT:'+data
```

Comment: The indentation of the code in your question is messed up.

Comment: Can you define "not get up and running"? Does it crash when you put messages on the queue? Does it crash when you take them off? Are you able to put them, but not read them?